Azure Durable Function Dynamic SQLDB_Connection string
I am currently working on azure durable function.
My Deployment strategy is local kubernetes cluster.
Config files looks like this:
local.settings.json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "SQLDB_Connection": "Server=localhost,1433;Database=DurableDB;User Id=sa;Password=ungabunga@Qtpie;",
    "KeyVaultUrl": "https://kvurl.vault.azure.net/"
  }
}

host.json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "durableTask": {
            "storageProvider": {
                "type": "mssql",
                "connectionStringName": "SQLDB_Connection",
                "createDatabaseIfNotExists": true
            }
        }
    },
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            },
            "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
        }
    }
}

I have a Program.cs in the root of the directory where i configure and run application as
var host = hostBuilder
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        var keyVaultUrl = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KeyVaultUrl");
        if (keyVaultUrl == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidConstraintException("KeyVaultUrl cannot be null");
        }

        services.ConfigureKeyVault(keyVaultUrl);
        services.AddHttpClient();
    })
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();

Is there any way that I can fetch sqldb connection string from kv and run the application? I am not able to find where the dependency is implemented and injected. SO on which function call on the hostBuilder i can invoke keyvault fetch changes and then initialize durable function db related dependencies manually and continue normal flow of the application.
Or my approach may be completely wrong and I should deploy this on Azure Portal itself.
Please help me here.
Dependencies are as below:
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.12.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets" Version="4.6.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.22.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="1.1.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask.SqlServer" Version="1.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.3.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0"/>


Can you share your durable function code?

@VivekVaibhavShandilya you mean functions? they are normal function with orchestrator as the initiator and other activity triggers

To fetch connection string from Key Vault, Key Vault reference can be used.
For reference check this Document.
It worked for me.
host.json:
{
    "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "durableTask": {
      "storageProvider": {
        "type": "mssql",
        "connectionStringName": "SQL_DB_CONN",
        "createDatabaseIfNotExists": true
      }
    }
  }
}

To use Key Vault reference follow the steps:

Deploy your function to azure enable system assigned identity/ add user assigned identity



Create a secrete in Key vault and add connection_string value in secret
Assign role to identity in Key Vault.



Add Environment Variable Key of connection string with value @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://<vault-name>.vault.azure.net/secrets/<secrete-name>/)



OUTPUT:


Thanks for the detailed response @vivek, let me take a look and comeback, btw what if i am using it locally and not on azure?

@silentsudo Unfortunately, Key Vault reference is not supported in locally AFAIK
